# How to scrape Onion websites (Dark Web) data using Selenium Python on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, darknet

I am unable to scrape data from onion websites from Dark Web using Selenium on windows 10 through TOR browser.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile 
import pandas as pd 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType 
import time

        
   

serv="C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Tor_Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Tor\\tor.exe" 
    
proxy = Proxy({
'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
'socksProxy': '127.0.0.1:9150',
'socksVersion': 5, })
            
            
options=Options() 
options.profile=FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Tor_Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default") 
options.binary_location=FirefoxBinary("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Tor_Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe")
 

binary=FirefoxBinary("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Tor_Browser\\Browser\\firefx.exe") 


binary.profile=FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Tor_Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default")

                
serv=Service("C:\\Program Files\\Gecko_Driver\\geckodriver.exe") 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,service=serv) 
url="http://archiveiya74codqgiixo33q62qlrqtkgmcitqx5u2oeqnmn5bpcbiyd.onion/"
                
driver.implicitly_wait(30) 
driver.get(url) 
print("program ran") 
time.sleep(10) 
     
driver.find_element("/html/body/center/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[1]")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try connecting through Geckodriver's binary path, it throws this error:

> tent/marionette/cert.js :: allowAllCerts.enable :: line 46"  data: no]
> Stacktrace:
> allowAllCerts.enable@chrome://remote/content/marionette/cert.js:46:23
> WebDriverSession@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Session.jsm:179:21
> createSession@chrome://remote/content/webdriver-bidi/WebDriverBiDi.jsm:88:21
> GeckoDriver.prototype.newSession@chrome://remote/content/marionette/driver.js:421:39
> despatch@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:306:40
> execute@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:279:16
> onPacket/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:252:20
> onPacket@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:253:9
> _onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/transport.js:500:20

[image]

Please suggest me a solution for scraping .onion websites using Python Selenium on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You Have Mistakes in

binary=FirefoxBinary("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Tor_Browser\Browser\firefx.exe")

Please correct firefx.exe into firefox.exe